# Does calling convention affect a context switch?

Tags: calling-convention, context-switch

Does it matter what my calling convention was for doing a context switch. As in, in AMD64, the first 4 parameters are passed via registers or something.

Does the context switch system need to worry about these details?

Answer (score 0):

A context switch needs to make sure that all thread context is saved: the stack, the CPU registers, and some additional OS-specific stuff.

Since the context switch is saving *everything*, it does not need to know about the calling convention. It is saving the registers, regardless of whether they happen to hold parameters of the current function, or some other data.